# Sharedpreferences in android studio

Tags: android

I've been starting to develop a pretty basic app but I cant use sharedpreference for some reason. The app crashes when it should be saved.

this is my code:

```
SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("details1",0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sp.edit();
    editor.putString("etName",etName.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("etLName",etLName.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("etCity",etCity.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("btnDateOfBirth",btnDateOfBirth.getText().toString());
    editor.putString("btnGender",btnGender.getText().toString());
    editor.commit();
```

I've declared on the variables needed. What might cause it to crash ?

Comment: can you post stacktrace and some more code.

Comment: Stacktrace mate, stacktrace. It's not happen "for some reason". It has a reason.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.text.Editable android.widget.EditText.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                                          at il.co.appschool.hw_ch7.MainActivity.saveDetails(MainActivity.java:110)
                                                                          at il.co.appschool.hw_ch7.MainActivity$HandleAlertDialogListener.onClick(MainActivity.java:101) edit:it happens also when it isnt null btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generally use this way to get the sharedPreferences of my application:

```
SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Also, you should provide the stack trace because the error could as well come from the `getText` methods you use for example? You say the variables are declared, but it's not enough. They have to point to an existing TextView or you get a null pointer exception.

Additional trick: you can chain the putX methods as they return the editor.

```
editor.putString("etName",etName.getText().toString())
    .putString("etLName",etLName.getText().toString())
    .putString("etCity",etCity.getText().toString())
    .putString("btnDateOfBirth",btnDateOfBirth.getText().toString())
    .putString("btnGender",btnGender.getText().toString())
    .commit();
```

EDIT : from the stacktrace it seems that `etName` is null. So you should ensure it points to an existing TextView. Typically:

```
etName = findViewById(R.id.et_text);
```

if your TextView (or EditText) has the id `et_text` in your XML layout.

Comment: It says the row the error occurs in is on the first put string row. So it might be there?

Comment: Ok I've seen your stacktrace you commented and as I said, the problem comes from the TextViews and has nothing to do with the shared preferences. Your variables must point to an existing TextView or it raises a null pointer exception.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replys btw. I pretty new to android developing so sorry in advance. My EditText variables werent null when I tried to use sp. HUGE EDIT:  I THINK U MIGHT BE RIGHT! LET ME CHECK AGAIN!

Comment: Well, you must be using EditText but EditText extends TextView (inherits) so I was being more general. Replace `TextView` with `EditText` and you should get it! ;)

Comment: Haha HUGE EDIT :') Ok I'll wait then. If it does work, then mark my answer as accepted!

Comment: IT WORKED! Thanks you so much for spending time on this! Such a beginner mistake on my part, didnt do the findviewbyid thing for the first name .. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the context to the getSharedPreference like

`Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences 
sp=context.getSharedPreferences("details1",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

You need to specify the context requesting the SharedPreference